# Javascript - Get Multiple Classes

Tags: javascript

How do I get either of multiple classes?

`document.getElementsByClassName("F-rank-good");` gets all the elements that have the classname `F-rank-good`. How do I get all the elements that have classname `F-rank-good` **OR** `F-rank-bad`?

`document.getElementsByClassName("F-rank-good F-rank-bad")` gets all the elements that have BOTH of those classes but I want it so it has *either* class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` does not support "or" as far as I know, but `querySelectorAll` does!

```
document.querySelectorAll(".F-rank-good, .F-rank-bad");
```

An easy way to see if `getElementsByClassName` does support it is to use the comma delimiter.

I suggest `querySelectorAll` either way, as the latter is supported in IE8

Comment: You're missing periods before the class names: `document.querySelectorAll(".F-rank-good, .F-rank-bad");`